h2o variable importance for GLM models in R
I ran a GLM model using h2o in r (the model was saved as an object called mod), the dataset contains categorical and continuous predictors. I called the h2o.varimp function on mod to retrieve the variable importance for this GLM model, for categorical predictors, it seemed to calculate the relative importance for each level within that same categorical predictor. Is there a way for me to aggregate the importance across all levels so that I get a single importance metric for each unique predictor?
I first tried summing the relative importance but since they are based on standardized coefficients, I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Hiya, welcome to SO. For people to help you they need a minimal reproducible example - guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

I think more appropriate is to do a weighted average since categorical variable has always only one value at a time and I would weigh it by the relative frequency of each level - imagine you have a very rare level that influences the target variable a lot. If you’d use average, this rare level would influence the relative importance more than it should.
Another possibility is to use SHAP via predict_contributions and set output_format = “compact”. This will give you coefficients multiplied by average value from each variable from the background_set. These contributions then sum up to the prediction (might be in link space so unless you’re using Gaussian regression, you might want to se output_space=TRUE). You can take the mean absolute value to get some feature importance.

Thanks for the response - I think using frequency to weigh the relative importance across the levels within a categorical predictor is reasonable; on the other hand, SHAP seems to work for only tree-based models and I'm curious if there are similar measures for GLMs.

In newer versions of H2O, SHAP works for all the models that are available in H2O’s AutoML (DeepLearning, DRF, GBM, GLM, StackedEnsemble, XGBoost). You just need to specify background_frame.
SHAP works on tree-based models even without background frame because we can use the structure of the trees to efficiently estimate how each feature influences the prediction. But even for tree-based models it’s usually better to estimate SHAP with background frame since it contains the information about distributions of individual variables.

Appreciated the feedback - do you know where I could find documentation regarding implementing SHAP on GLMs or non tree-based models in general?

Most of the papers that were used for implementing the SHAP should be in h2o’s documentation https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html . You can also check the references from the PR that added the SHAP to H2O: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/15734 (I’m lazy and I didn’t update the PR’s description so some of the issues there mentioned are already resolved). If you want specifically GLM SHAP then you can have a look at this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.16234 and https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-31384-3 for the conversion from link space.

Another reason that only standardized coefficients are used in the calculation of variable importance is due to the scaling of the different predictors.  A predictor A that is in the range of 0 to 1 and another predictor B is in the range of 10000-200000. I know that both predictors contribute equally to the final model output.
For example, A = 0.5, B = 20000, y = 40000.  Then, in this case, we will have 40000A+1B = 40000.  Hence, the variable importance without standardization will give you the impression that predictor A is much more important than predictor B which is incorrect.  They participated equally in generating the model output and the two should have the same variable importance.

Thanks - the idea of using standardized coefficients to measure variable importance makes sense to me as they are scale independent. What I'm struggling with is how to aggregate these coefficients so that I can have a single number for each predictor (given that each level within a categorical predictor has its own coefficient)
